# блок synchronized: пустые и указывающие на класс параметры

Tags: java

```
class ThreadRun implements Runnable {

Application application;
public ThreadRun(Application application) {
    this.application = application;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    application.core(application);
}}

public class Program {

public static void main(String[] args)  {
    Application application = new Application();

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        new Thread(new ThreadRun(new Application())).start();
    }
}}
```

Объясните, почему если написать что-то такое, то блок synchronized в любом случае заставлять потоки ждать, даже если передать новый объект при создании потока

```
class Application {
 void core(Application application) {
    synchronized ("") {
        //code
    }

    synchronized (YourClass.class) {
        //code
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В случае с

```
synchronized ("") {
    // code
}
```

Синхронизация осуществляется по объекту класса `String`, поэтому стоит обратить внимание, что в данном случае объект строки не создается с явным использованием конструктора `new String()`. Поэтому из блока синхронизации осуществляется обращение в String Pool, где хранится **только однин экземпляр строки ""**. Заменив `""` на `new String("")` в разных потоках будут использованы разные объекты синхронизации.

Что касается

```
synchronized (YourClass.class) {
    // code
}
```

Здесь синхронизация осуществляется по Объекту класса `Java.lang.Class<YourClass>`. Класс `Class` широко применяется в рефлексии, но в нашем случае важно знать, что элемент класса `Class<YourClass>` создается JVM при первом обращении к статическим полям/методам класса или при создании первого экземпляра класса и в последующем возвращает его. Поэтому синхронизация будет осуществляться по одному экземпляру объекта.